# How to call load URL using HTTP POST inside the HTML frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http, frames

I have a jsp page where I am using HTML frames.

As usual I have included 2 html frames inside the jsp page like this :

```
  <frameset rows="50%,50%">
      <frame src="www.acclaris.com" />
      <frame src="www.forms.acclaris.com" />
      <noframes>
      <body>
      Your browser does not support frames.
      </body>
      </noframes>
   </frameset>
```

But according to the requirement, www.acclaris.com and www.forms.acclaris.com, both URL should be called by passing some authentication parameter(P_TOKEN) in the HTTP post request.

So , both URL needs to be called by passing P_TOKEN as the POST parameter so that server authenticates the user.

It is **strictly prohibited to pass parameter using HTTP GET**.

Is this possible to call a URL using HTTP post method in an HTML frame ?

Comment: 1999 called, they want their frames back. You could for example use a page that POSTs to the form page using JavaScript.